# How to test against a list of items in an if statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large table (130 columns).  It is a monthly dataset that is separated by month (jan,feb,mar,...).  every month I get a small set of duplicate rows.  I would like to remove one of the rows, it does not matter which row to be deleted.

This query seems to work ok when I only select the ID that I want to filter the dups on, but when I select everything `"*"` from the table I end up with all of the rows, dups included.  My goal is to filter out the dups and insert the result set into a new table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[ID]
FROM MonthlyLoan a
    JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as Count, b.[ID]
            FROM MonthlyLoan b
            GROUP BY b.[ID])
        AS b ON a.[ID] = b.[ID]
WHERE b.Count > 1
and effectiveDate = '01/31/2017'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use that query in a CTE or sub-query, and inner join the results of that back to the SELECT * from MonthlyLoan on ID, and you should get what you want. Basically, you have a query that gives you the Distinct IDs you want, and by joining that back to the original table, you get the full set of columns for just those rows.

Comment: If your **ID** is dupped all your need is to `group by ID` and use a `HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1`

Comment: Great question, unfortunately, a common occurrence. See the answer from @Phoenix below, we actually use that solution without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

This will show you all duplicates per ID:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS
(
     SELECT ID
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
     FROM MonthlyLoan
)
SELECT ID,
       rn
FROM Duplicates
WHERE rn > 1
```

Alternatively, you can set `rn = 2` to find the immediate duplicate per ID.

Comment: You can take this one step further, and actually delete from `MonthlyLoad` directly via the `CTE`. Just update the query right after the `CTE` to `DELETE` instead of a `SELECT`. We actually use that in a certain set of vendor-supplied unclean data.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ID is dupped (A DUPPED ID!!!!)

all you need it to use the `HAVING` clause in your aggregate.
See the below example.

```
declare @tableA as table 
(
   ID int not null
)

insert into @tableA
values
(1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(4),(5)

select ID, COUNT(*) as [Count]
from @tableA
group by ID
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
ID          Count
----------- -----------
2           2
3           3
```

To insert the result into a #Temporary Table:

```
select ID, COUNT(*) as [Count]
into #temp
from @tableA
group by ID
having COUNT(*) > 1

select * from #temp
```